# How do I remove a GitHub status check?

Tags: github, teamcity, github-api

I have a GitHub status check generated by TeamCity, and I'm trying to delete it (not just disable it).

I've tried (line breaks added for readability):

```
curl -u <myusername>:<mytoken>
 -X DELETE
https://:github_instance/api/v3/repos/:user/:repo/statuses/:hash
```

I got the url from:

```
curl -u <myusername>:<mytoken> 
https://:github_instance/api/v3/repos/:user/:repo/statuses/:branch_name
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can overwrite a status by name. See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78518 for a working solution

Comment: Having the same issue.

Comment: @gabel overwriting does not a delete make though, does it? It'd be cleaner if an actual delete were possible, no?

Comment: @jameslafferty No it doesn't but as you can overwrite the context you could do something like..  PROCESS-A: pending --- overwrite it with CANCELED: successful

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I see the [GitHub API V3 Repository Statuses](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/) (for github.com or for a private GitHub enterprise instance) includes:

- Create a status
- List statuses for a specific ref
- Get the combined status for a specific ref

There is no deletion as far as I can see.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see anything there either. Was hoping someone knew something beyond the documentation. Le sigh. I'll keep on holding my breath for a solution, but you get my upvote.

Comment: Boo! It looks like this _is_ the actual answer, which is lame. But points to @VonC!

Answer (score 28):

Like @VonC I couldn't find a deletion option.  However, you can disable any existing checks so that they no longer run on your PRs.

```
Settings
  Branches
    Branch protection rules  
      Edit (next to your desired branch, e.g. 'master')  
        Rule settings  
          Require status checks to pass before merging
            Require branches to be up to date before merging 
              < Uncheck any statuses you want to disable! >
```

Comment: Interesting alternative. +1

Comment: I'll vote this up, as folks might find it useful. I still think @VonC's answer remains correct. It'd be nice if GitHub provided a real solution.

Comment: This does not actually remove the status check from running, only from preventing a failed status check from blocking a merge.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution now returns a "Rule is invalid" error when trying to enable it.

Comment: > Unfortunately, this solution now returns a "Rule is invalid" error when trying to enable it.

You must specify a branch pattern so just put *