# is it possible to fix the github actions error tips in project board

Tags: github-actions

Today I am facing a issue that the github project main board always show [error](https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/ai-web) even through all github action build success, is it possible to fixed this issue? this is the main board:

[image]

all of the github actions build success, why the main board still shows failed status? I have already tried to find the status check hooks and try to close it but did not found any `check tasks/branch protection rules/hooks` with the branch:

[image]

Comment: Have you verified the commit SHA with all the successful workflow runs?

Comment: If you click on the status icon, you should see the individual checks. Are they all green?

Comment: Looks like the check "bizarre cover - ai-web" failed.

Comment: I also found the  "bizarre cover - ai-web" failed but did not found a entrypont or way to remove the error log. @BenjaminW.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a GitHub status check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48106989/how-do-i-remove-a-github-status-check)

Comment: I have no action check task. @BenjaminW.

Comment: "bizarre cover - ai-web" is a status check, isn't it? I believe the answer to your question is: it's not possible.

Comment: I followed the anwser but did not found the status check hook with the main branch.